# Unable to install new OS (Possibly MBR related)

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uefi, mbr

I am trying to make my system dual boot. I am currently using ubuntu 16.04 and my linux kernel is 4.15 . I use an asus laptop (year old model) although it says "Asus Bios Utiliy" i am pretty sure this is a UEFI system. I need to install and use windows for a group project. I am constantly getting errors which I will add the photos of.

First I want to tell a couple of stuff which i think my problem is not related to and reasons for them , than what i think the problem is and why.

- I downloaded windows 7 and windows 8 from my uni servers so i believe iso's are okay.
- I burned the iso's to 2 different usb sticks (one of them is brand new for this purpose) , and also i burned the iso using 2 different methods in ubuntu and one in windows (my friends pc). So i don't think there is a problem in that process.
- Also i used a tool called "boot-repair" did not fix it

I think the reason i am having this is issue is: I used windows for a couple of week 4-5 months ago. When i switched back to ubuntu i did not properly delete windows (not sure if there is a proper way but..) , i directly wrote ubuntu onto windows. A friend of mine (junior year computer programming student) said windows still would have data in mbr and it is very hard to get rid of it. I think this is true because even before i tried to install windows again in grub i could see windows. When i choose it gave an error of course but i strongly believe there are some files from the old windows left there. I am no expert but i think it is somehow related , i almost literally tried everything i read on the web, still no solution.

Here are ss's:
https://ibb.co/jiSDb7
https://ibb.co/mdPbW7
https://ibb.co/eQA5PS

Thank You

Comment: These are image of windows errors. This is not related to ubuntu.

Comment: Please check if Legacy BIOS is turned on in your BIOS/UEFI setup. Then check if your hard drive has MBR or GPT. Then **edit your question above** and add the answers in the question. If you have Legacy turned on, you may use MBR, if legacy is turned off, then GPT. Any other combination may not work with Windows.

Comment: If a year old system, it is UEFI. But if you force install Windows 7 without converting it to UEFI, it defaults to BIOS boot. And then incorrectly converts drive from gpt to MBR(msdos). Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info  ASUS X540U pci=noaer instead of pci=nomsi and it also worked
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391201
Problems Installing on ASUS F555U   needed boot option pci=nomsi
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2303665

Comment: @oldfred http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Dw8qX5YGyG/ , this is my summary. I do not mind using windows 8 over windows 7 , i really do not want to use windows 10 but if it is the only one possible for me i would use it too. To be honest i do not fully understand what you've said but if you need any other report or something like that from my pc i would be happy to give.

Comment: @solsTiCe I don't think so because when i plug it my friends (windows) pc and double click to setup executable in it it start installing.

Comment: @solsTiCe I used the usb on another pc i boots through usb and win8 installation starts. No problem with iso

Comment: You have installed or repaired Ubuntu install with both BIOS & UEFI boot. Your BIOS boot will not work, but UEFI boot should work. But do boot USB installer, you have to choose that from UEFI boot menu. You may have to turn on allow USB boot or full USB access setting. With gpt partitioned drive, you have to boot Windows installer in UEFI mode as it will only install in UEFI mode to gpt partitioned drive. Windows 7 installer is BIOS only, but can be converted to flash drive and modified to make it UEFI bootable to install in UEFI mode if desired.